# SQL CASE in Query - Odd behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using a Case Statement in a query seems to work fine as long as the only case you want to match to is a string. But if you want to put ">" greater than (date or number), etc, SSMS automatically adds apostrophes around your statement (below) as if it were a string.

How can I get it to accept "greater than date" or "greater than number", etc??

[image: SSMS Adds ' around operators used in a CASE Statement in a Query]

Comment: Don't use the Query Designer?

Comment: The query designer in SQL server is about as (un)intelligent as the one in MS Acess. Just modify the raw SQL code yourself to fix the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> - The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
> - The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

You want a *searched* CASE expression. This means that the WHEN should come *immediately* after the CASE keyword.

```
CASE WHEN SoldDate <= SubjectDate THEN ...
```

Comment: +1 - Sorry for the closeness of our answers, you expanded yours as I was writing mine :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of `CASE` expressions ([from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)):

A **Simple** `CASE` compares the specified expression for **EQUIVALENCY ONLY**

`SELECT FieldName CASE WHEN 'Blah' THEN 'Foo' ELSE 'Bah' END`

A **Searched** `CASE` can do inequalities too but has more verbose syntax:

`SELECT CASE WHEN FieldName >= 'Blah' THEN 'Foo' ELSE 'Bah' END`

You are trying to use the **Simple** syntax and need to use the **Searched** syntax by explicitly writing out the fieldname and comparison for each evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE` statement syntax is incorrect. `WHEN` should come directly after `CASE`

**This:**

```
CASE SoldDate WHEN ...
```

**Should be this:**

```
CASE WHEN SoldDate <= SubjectDate THEN SoldFor ELSE EstSalePrice END
```

**Additional Information**

Take a look at [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for additional examples of `CASE` syntax.